# I need to make this code more efficient, for example the minor errors

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, csv

I've tried learning StreamWriter which didn't work out well (lack of resources). I would appreciate any books or website suggestions also.

```
Dim decision As Char
Dim fullline As String = " "

Dim word(9), def(9), minorerror1(49), minorerror2(49), minorerror3(49), minorerror4(49), minorerror5(49) As String
Dim datetime(1) As System.DateTime

Console.WriteLine("3 - Year 3")
Console.WriteLine("4 - Year 4")
Console.WriteLine("5 - Year 5")
Console.WriteLine("6 - Year 6")

Console.WriteLine()

Dim testyear As Integer = Console.ReadLine()

Select Case testyear
    Case 1
    Case 2
    Case 3
    Case 4
End Select

Console.WriteLine("Please enter 10 of your selected words, defenitions and selected amount minor errors to be featured in the following test")

FileOpen(5, "F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\testtests.csv", OpenMode.Append)

Do
    counter = counter + 1
    Console.Write("Word: ")
    word(counter) = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("Defenition: ")
    def(counter) = Console.ReadLine

    Console.WriteLine("Type in a max of 5 minor errors")

    Console.Write("Minor error 1: ")
    minorerror1(counter) = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("Minor error 2: ")
    minorerror2(counter) = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("Minor error 3: ")
    minorerror3(counter) = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("Minor error 4: ")
    minorerror4(counter) = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("Minor error 5: ")
    minorerror5(counter) = Console.ReadLine
Loop Until counter = 9
Console.Clear()

For counter As Integer = 0 To 9
    fullline = word(counter) & "," & def(counter) & "," & minorerror1(counter) & "," & minorerror2(counter) & "," & minorerror3(counter) & "," & minorerror4(counter) & "," & minorerror5(counter)
    PrintLine(5, fullline)
    Console.WriteLine("Word: " & (word(counter.ToString)) & " Defenition: " & (def(counter.ToString)) & " Minor error 1: " & (minorerror1(counter.ToString)) & " Minor error 2: " & (minorerror2(counter.ToString))& " Minor error 3: " & (minorerror3(counter.ToString))& " Minor error 4: " & (minorerror4(counter.ToString))& " Minor error 5: " & (minorerror5(counter.ToString))
Next
```

'the bit above definitely needs polishing, but I don't really know how to store the minor errors.

```
Console.WriteLine("Are you sure you want to save this test? (y/n) ")
decision = Console.ReadLine
If decision = "y" Or decision = "Y" Then
    FileClose(5)
    staffmenu()
ElseIf decision = "n" Or decision = "N" Then
    addtest()
End If
```

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter-vbnet also you should get used to something on the lines of `decision.ToLower().Trim()` when you are dealing with inputs and a condition.

Comment: If this is working code, it would be better off on [codereview.se].

Comment: Also I see this code much better than your previous one and not sure what is the problem now with the minor errors. Are not they being stored rightly in the corresponding arrays?

Comment: They are getting stored well, the code works fine, but isn't this very amateur?

Comment: you could use stringbuilder to build each line in the input loop, and just store as a List(Of String) to be written out.  this would get rid of the word(), def() and numerous minorerror() arrays and make it easier to read. If you dont process the arrays, consider getting rid of them.  then just write out the List of strings.  StreamWriter and no VB FileXXXX ops would be a little better.    Also you spelled `Definition` wrong.

Comment: I know, I always spell that bugger wrong, same with "Address", I spell it "Adress". And thanks for the advice; I'll look into string builders. And if you guys know any good books I could buy on vb.net could you inform me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problems with `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` as I have just learnt them myself. If it helps, this is possibly the most basic you can get but it really does get you going. With basic knowledge of looping and similar constructs, `StreamWriter` can become pretty powerful:

[image: Basic StreamWriter]

And `StreamReader`:

[image: Basic StreamReader]

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim myLines As New List(of String)
Dim sb as StringBuilder

For counter As Integer = 0 To 9

   sb = New StringBuilder

   Console.Write("Word: ")
   sb.Append(Console.ReadLine & ", ")

   Console.Write("Defenition: ")            ' (sic)
   sb.Append(Console.ReadLine & ", ")

   Console.WriteLine("Type in a max of 5 minor errors")

  ' the five (? - the arrays are set much larger)
  ' minor errors can be an inner loop:
   For j as integer = 1 to 5                 ' zero based confuses users
       Console.Write("Minor error " & j.ToString & ": ")
       sb.Append(Console.ReadLine & ", ")
   Next j

   myLines.Add(sb.ToString)

Next counter

Using sw As New StreamWriter("theFileName.CSV")
   For n As Integer = 0 to myLines.Count - 1
        sw.WriteLine(myLines(n))
   Next n
End Using
```

That should be pretty close

Comment: sorry, use "sb.ToString"  AKA pretty close

Comment: check off the answer if it helped...gain yourself some rep in the process

Comment: to be honest, the thing I use most is the object browser (F2) to fish out props, methods etc.  Then of course, MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make in more efficient or just more flexible/manageable?

If you're reading from the console five times in each iteration of the loop there's little point in trying to speed it up; or even getting (imho) into stringbuilder.

A more flexible solutions would be:

Const MaxNumberOfMinorErrors as integer = 5

Dim Minorerror(MaxNumberOfMinorErrors - 1, 9) as string

...

For x as Integer = 1 to MaxNumberOfMinorErrors

```
Console.WriteLine("Minor error {0}: ", x)
minorerror(x- 1, Counter) = Console.ReadLine
```

Next